# Give a quiz 2 right answers

Tags: python, user-input

For the month of February I am trying to make it so it has 3 correct answers for the number of days in the month 28,29 29 28 but it doesn't seem to be working when I try to change

```
user = int(input(""))

if month == "January":
   answer = 31
elif month == "Feburary":
   answer = 28
```

to

```
user = int(input(""))

if month == "January":
   answer = 31
elif month == "Feburary (use comma to seperate two numbers)":
   answer = 28,29 or 28 or 29
```

I realise that there is a problem with using integer in the input but I am not sure how to fix that with the comma and it won't let me put a space in between the 28 and 29 .

This is the rest of the code:

```
import random
import shelve
from tkinter import * 
result = []
highscore = []

root = Tk()  

highscore = 0
correct = 0
d = shelve.open('highscore.txt')   
d['highscore'] = highscore           
d.close()

name = input("What is your name: ")
print ("Hello there",name,"!")
for count in range(12):
    month = random.choice(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",     "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"])
while month in result:
    month = random.choice(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"])
result.append(month)
print ("How many Days in?", month)
user = int(input(""))

if month == "January":
   answer = 31
elif month == "February":
   answer = 28,29 or 29 or 28
elif month == "March":
   answer = 31
elif month == "April":
   answer = 30
elif month == "May":
   answer = 31
elif month == "June":
   answer = 30
elif month == "July":
   answer = 31
elif month == "August":
   answer = 31
elif month == "September":
   answer = 30
elif month == "October":
   answer = 31
elif month == "November":
   answer = 30
elif month == "December":
   answer = 31

if user == answer:
    print("Correct!")
    correct = correct + 1
else:
    print ("Wrong, the correct answer was", answer)

if correct > highscore:
    highscore = correct
    print (name,", You Beat The Highscore and got",highscore,"Out Of 12")
    photo = PhotoImage(file='/Users/HoneyCentaur/Desktop/Approval.gif')
    photo_label = Label(image=photo)
    photo_label.grid()             
    photo_label.image = photo      

text = Label(text="  ")
text.grid()    

root.deiconify()
root.mainloop()
else:
    print (name, ", You Got", correct, "Out Of 12")

d = shelve.open('highscore.txt')  
d['highscore'] = highscore           
d.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely want to use a `list` to check if the `user` answer was in the list of possible answers for the number of days in a month. you can then use the `in` keyword in python check if `user` is in the possible answers list.

The code would look a bit like the following:

```
if month == "Janurary":
  answer=[31]
elif month == "Feburary":
  answer=[28,29]

if user in answer:
    print("Correct!")
    correct = correct + 1
```

**EDIT #1**

Keep in mind there are many other options for going at this. To have a single element in a  list kind of defeats the purpose and hinders understandability.

A better option might be to just cast the users answer from `28` to `29` or vice-a-versa if you're just using it to count points:

```
if month == "Janurary":
  answer=31
elif month == "Feburary":
  if(user == 28):
    user = 29
  answer=29

if user in answer:
    print("Correct!")
    correct = correct + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe "or" is only used for boolean or comparison operations.
i.e.

`if month == "Janurary" or month == "Feburary":
    do_something`

if the quiz is looking for the possible "last days" of a month, I'm assuming the function would want a list of options.

`if month == "Janurary":
  answer=[31]
elif month == "Feburary":
  answer=[28,29]`